# Replace values in vector where not %in% vector

Tags: r

Short question:

I can substitute certain variable values like this:

```
values <- c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b")
df <- data.frame(values)
```

What's the easiest way to replace all the values of df$values by "x" (where the value is *neither* "a" or "b")?

Output should be:

```
c("a", "b", "a", "b", "x", "a", "b")
```

Comment: do you mean `df <- data.frame(values)`?

Comment: What is `x`? Why isn't `values` in the data frame. Please share a complete example along with expected output

Comment: sure, sorry... I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is a bit unclear and not reproducible.
However, based on guessing what you actually want, I could suggest trying this option using the data.table package:

```
df[values %in% c("a", "b"), values := "x"]
```

or the dplyr package:

```
df %>% mutate(values = ifelse(values %in% c("a","b"), x, values))
```

Comment: sorry, after your edit it became more clear what you meant and it is indeed what I suspected. let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
df[!df[, 1] %in% c("a", "b"), ] <- "x"

  values
1      a
2      b
3      a
4      b
5      x
6      a
7      b
```